# ¿Cómo decorar todas las peticiones HTTP para tomar un valor de la cabecera y agregarlo en un parámetro del cuerpo?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring, rest, cabeceras-http

Adaptado y traducido de: [How to decorate all requests to take a value from header and add it in the body parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36295095/1065197)

### Trasfondo

Estoy creando una serie de servicios RESTful utilizando Spring MVC. Actualmente, tengo la siguiente estructura para un controlador:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "myEntity", produces="application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public class MyEntityController {

    @RequestMapping(path={ "", "/"} , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> createMyEntity(
        @RequestBody MyEntity myEntity,
        @RequestHeader("X-Client-Name") String clientName) {
        myEntity.setClientName(clientName);
        //resto de declaración del método...
    }

    @RequestMapping(path={ "/{id}"} , method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> updateMyEntity(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @RequestBody MyEntity myEntity,
        @RequestHeader("X-Client-Name") String clientName) {
        myEntity.setClientName(clientName);
        //resto de declaración del método...
    }

    @RequestMapping(path={ "/{id}"} , method=RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> partialUpdateMyEntity(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @RequestBody MyEntity myEntity,
        @RequestHeader("X-Client-Name") String clientName) {
        myEntity.setClientName(clientName);
        //resto de declaración del método...
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver, estos tres métodos reciben el mismo parámetro para la cabecera `@RequestHeader("X-Client-Name") String clientName` y se aplica de la misma manera en cada método: `myEntity.setClientName(clientName)`. Crearé controladores similares y para las operaciones POST, PUT and PATCH van a contener un código similar pero orientado a otras entidades. Actualmente, la mayoría de las entidades están diseñadas para soportar este campo a través de una clase padre:

```
public class Entity {
    protected String clientName;
    //getters y setters ...
}
public class MyEntity extends Entity {
    //...
}
```

Nota, utilizo un interceptor para verificar que la cabecera está puesta en las peticiones.

### Pregunta

¿Cómo puedo evitar repetir el mismo código en los controladores y métodos? ¿Existe una manera limpia de lograr esto, sin repetición de código? ¿O estoy condenado a repetir el parámetro y la misma línea de código en todos los métodos de mis controladores futuros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en la respuesta de [@PaulVargas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6518/227) y a una idea de @jasilva (usar herencia) pude llegar a una solución más robusta para lo que necesito. En resumen, se divide en dos partes:

1. Utilizar una clase base para los controladores. Llamaré a este `BaseController<E extends Entity>` puesto que `Entity` es la clase principal de mis entidades. En esta clase capturaré el valor del parámetro `@RequestBody E entity` y lo asignaré en `@ModelAttribute` tal como explica @PaulVargas en su respuesta. El poder de los genéricos entra en esta parte.
2. En mis controladores, extenderé de `BaseController<ProperEntity>` donde `ProperEntity` es la clase de entidad que necesito procesar para que la inyección sea automática.

Aquí muestro el código para el diseño descrito:

```
//1.
public abstract class BaseController<E extends Entity> {

    @ModelAttribute("entity")
    public E populate(
            @RequestBody(required=false) E myEntity,
            @RequestHeader("X-Client-Name") String clientName) {
        if (myEntity != null) {
            myEntity.setCreatedBy(clientName);
        }
        return myEntity;
    }
}
```

```
//2.
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "myEntity", produces="application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public class MyEntityController extends BaseController<MyEntity> {

    @RequestMapping(path={ "", "/"} , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> createMyEntity(
        @ModelAttribute("entity") MyEntity myEntity) {
        //resto de declaración del método...
    }

    @RequestMapping(path={ "/{id}"} , method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> updateMyEntity(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @ModelAttribute("entity") MyEntity myEntity) {
        //resto de declaración del método...
    }

    @RequestMapping(path={ "/{id}"} , method=RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> partialUpdateMyEntity(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @ModelAttribute("entity") MyEntity myEntity) {
        //resto de declaración del método...
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Es posible remover algo del código repetido utilizando la clase [`org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html). Es decir:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "myEntity", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class MyEntityController {

    @ModelAttribute("model")
    public MyEntity populate(
            @RequestBody MyEntity myEntity,
            @RequestHeader("X-Client-Name") String clientName) {
        myEntity.setClientName(clientName);
        return myEntity;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> createMyEntity(
            @ModelAttribute("model") MyEntity myEntity) {
        ⋮
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = {"/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> updateMyEntity(
            @PathVariable Long id,
            @ModelAttribute("model") MyEntity myEntity) {
        ⋮
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = {"/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> partialUpdateMyEntity(
            @PathVariable Long id,
            @ModelAttribute("model") MyEntity myEntity) {
        ⋮
    }

}
```

El método `populate` será invocado en cada petición hacia este controlador  antes de invocar los métodos anotados con `@RequestMapping`.

---

Puesto que este método siempre se ejecuta en cada petición, un *payload* y un encabezado (`"X-Client-Name"`) son requeridos, incluso para aquellos métodos que no hacen uso de tales datos y una excepción es *lanzada* si no *viajan* en la petición. Puede modificarse ese requisito con el atributo `required = false`. Es decir:

```
    @ModelAttribute("model")
    public MyEntity populate(
            @RequestBody(required = false) MyEntity myEntity,
            @RequestHeader(required = false, value = "X-Client-Name") String clientName) {
        if (myEntity != null) {
            myEntity.setClientName(clientName);
        }
        return myEntity;
    }
```